# Deal connection lost in ActionScript 3

Tags: json, actionscript-3

I have this code:

```
public function Json2Me(_urlJSON:String) {
            var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
            request.url = _urlJSON;
            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaderComplete);
            loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,informadorIO);
            loader.load(request);
        }

        private function onLoaderComplete(e:Event):void{
            var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(e.target);
            JSONEnviado = com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON.decode(loader.data);
            dispatchEvent(new Event("LanzaJSON"));
        }

        public function informadorIO(e:Event):void{
            trace(e);
        }
```

I need to protect my code against connection lost, so what I have to do to keep my project running?

Answer (score 1):

You can catch the IO errors on url loader:

```
loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);

private function ioErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void {
    // URLLoader io failed
    trace("ioErrorHandler: " + event);
    // retry Json2Me maybe? How many times before you fail completely? Notify user?
    Json2Me("https://someurl.com/xxxxx")
}
```

Also the uncaughtErrorEvents on the Loader/LoaderInfo can catch things like not even having a network connection.

> LoaderInfo.uncaughtErrorEvents: to detect uncaught errors in code
>   defined in the same SWF. Loader.uncaughtErrorEvents: to detect
>   uncaught errors in code defined in the SWF loaded by a Loader object.

Example:

```
loaderInfo.uncaughtErrorEvents.addEventListener(UncaughtErrorEvent.UNCAUGHT_ERROR, onUncaughtError);

private function onUncaughtError(e:UncaughtErrorEvent):void {
    e.preventDefault();
    trace("onUncaughtError!!! - " + e.toString());
    // Notify user of failure?...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a [`HTTPStatusEvent`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/HTTPStatusEvent.html) which can give use the returned HTTP status ( or even the returned HTTP response headers for an AIR app ) :

```
var url_loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader()
    url_loader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS, on_http_status);  // works only for AIR
    url_loader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, on_http_status);
    url_loader.load(new URLRequest('http://www.example.com'))

function on_http_status(e:HTTPStatusEvent): void 
{
    trace(e.type);              // gives, for example : httpStatus 
    trace(e.status);            // gives, for example : 200
}
```

Hope that can help.